# Sending an oracle EXEC statement to the DB through sqlalchemy

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy, exec

I wrote this function to take in three parameters and a database connection, execute a function, and then pull from a view that is populated by the function.

```
def get_customer_data(start_date, end_date, segment, con):
    """ Get customer data
    """

    # This executes a process in the database that populates
    # my_view which we will subsequently pull from.
    sql = """EXEC PROCESS_POPULATE_VIEW ('%s','%s','%s');
    """ % (str(start_date), str(end_date), segment)

    con.execute(sql)

    sql = "SELECT * FROM MY_VIEW"

    return pd.read_sql(sql, con)
```

This is what I get back:

```
DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement [SQL: "EXEC PROCESS_POPULATE_VIEW ('11-JUN-2018','13-JUN-2018','Carrier');\n    "] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/4xp6)
```

Am I not allowed to call the EXEC command from sqlalchemy? Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: EXEC is a SQL\*Plus command, not SQL.

Comment: (i) use BEGIN and END around the PL/SQL procedure name (ii) pass the parameters by using bind variables instead of insecure and unscalable string concatenation.    See the sample or tutorial https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/tree/master/samples/tutorial